# Ошибка при установке mysqlclient

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pip, dockerfile

У меня есть Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip libmysqlclient-dev \
  && pip3 install pika chardet tldextract xlrd openpyxl python-memcached mysqlclient

CMD cd /opt/uploader \
  && (python3 RabbitMQWorker.py &) \
  && (python3 RabbitMQWorkerBlacklist.py &) \
  && sleep infinity
```

Раньше все работало норм, теперь выдает ошибку

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-jsb8kzwo/mysqlclient/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-2qjifjsq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-jsb8kzwo/mysqlclient/
```

Пробовал разные варианты, не помогало, вернул все назад, заработало, но на другом компьютере тож же докерфайл не работает, а на моем теперь выдает ошибки по синтаксису, не находит библиотеку openpyxl, хотя в докерфайле она есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для `mysqlclient` нужно ещё дополнительно ставить `libssl-dev` через `apt-get`.

Comment: Поставил, заработало, возникла другая проблема - не работает код
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
выдает SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @JonnyManowar, это уже ошибка в вашем коде.

Comment: это странно потому что openpyxl устанавливается без проблем, но при этом в коде его не находит

Comment: Установил python3-openpyxl через apt-get и заработало